# Set permission and ownership correctly, still getting "storage/logs/laravel.log" Permission denied

Tags: file-permissions, nginx, centos-7, selinux

There are lots of Q&As for this problem:

```
"storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

The solution, correctly, is to set the right permissions for right owners and groups. So I did:

Nginx group is `nginx` as `nginx -V` output says:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.12.2
built by gcc 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16) (GCC)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: ... --user=nginx --group=nginx ...
```

My files and directories's group is set to `nginx`:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:nginx /path/to/project
```

I set 755 for directories and 644 for files:

```
sudo find /path/to/project -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;    
sudo find /path/to/project -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

Then I set 775 for `storage`:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 storage
```

So I confirm that `storage/logs/laravel.log` permissions are `775` or `-rwxrwxr-x`.

But still I'm getting permission denied error on this file. I tried to change the owner to `nginx` as well with no luck, and also, I disabled `selinux` completely.

Any suggestions?

<sup>(Or should've posted it on stackoverflow.com instead?)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I fix mine with this line:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data storage
```

Hope helps